# Need to sort the Javascript object according to some logic

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a lot of objects like this

```
{
    "id": "c7c4acf4-8d4a-5c4c-839b-0f3f423aeb67",
    "frontmatter": {
        "slug": "/media/video/5",
        "title": "Here is the title 5",
        "author": "author_name",
        "date": "Apr 26, 2023",
        "length": 12,
        "featured": false,
        "excerpt": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Tellus nunc semper. and then if it says anything else we are truncating because we don’t need anything else.",
        "video": "https://www.twitch.tv/videos/106400740",
        "views": 547,
        "category": "video",
        "audio": "",
        "banner_image": null,
        "card_image": {
            "publicURL": "/static/112f4a4e7574b07442858554510b1923/Frame1.png"
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to sort the data base on this logic

sum(length(audio)) + sum(length(video)) + (sum(length(excerpt)) / 250)

```
if (sort.value.toLowerCase() === mediaSortItems.Length) {
    console.log(posts);
    const min = 60;
    const average_word_per_minutes = 250;
    let arr = posts.sort((a, b) => {
      let first = a.node.frontmatter;
      let second = b.node.frontmatter;
      if (
        first.audio
          ? first.length * min
          : 0 + first.video
          ? first.length * min
          : 0 + first.excerpt.length() / average_word_per_minutes > second.audio
          ? second.length * min
          : 0 + second.video * min
          ? second.length
          : 0 + second.excerpt.length() / average_word_per_minutes
      ) {
        return -1;
      }
    });

    return arr;
  }
```

I tried to do that but it didn't work

Comment: If you have one object, what is there to sort? What is `number_of_excerpt`? What is the `length` function?

Comment: They are a lot, but I give you a copy for one object

Comment: What about the other questions I asked? Also, you write you tried, but can you include your actual code that didn't work, including the definition of the functions you call (`sum`, `length`, ...etc)? I have honestly no idea what `sum(length(audio))` means. What is being summed?

Comment: I added my code

Comment: Why all the ternaries (`?` and `:`)? Seems like you just want to add values and see which is longer. Unless you have a hierarchy in your sort (i.e. if same last name, order by first name), you should not need boolean operations (you just return the difference between the values)